# LINQ with Querying "Memory"

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Does `LINQ` have a way to "memorize" its previous query results *while querying*?

Consider the following case:

```
public class Foo {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if two or more `Foo` have same collection of `Bar` (no matter what the order is), they are considered as **similar** `Foo`.

Example:

```
foo1.Bars = new List<Bar>() { bar1, bar2 };
foo2.Bars = new List<Bar>() { bar2, bar1 };
foo3.Bars = new List<Bar>() { bar3, bar1, bar2 };
```

In the above case, `foo1` is **similar** to `foo2` but both `foo1` and `foo2` are *not* **similar** to`foo3`

Given that we have a `query` result consisting `IEnumerable` or `IOrderedEnumerable` of `Foo`. From the `query`, we are to find the first `N` `foo` which are *not* **similar**.

This task seems to require a memory of the collection of `bars` which have been chosen before.

With *partial* `LINQ` we could do it like this:

```
private bool areBarsSimilar(ICollection<Bar> bars1, ICollection<Bar> bars2) {
    return bars1.Count == bars2.Count && //have the same amount of bars
        !bars1.Select(x => x.Id)
        .Except(bars2.Select(y => y.Id))
        .Any(); //and when excepted does not return any element mean similar bar
}

public void somewhereWithQueryResult(){
    .
    .
    List<Foo> topNFoos = new List<Foo>(); //this serves as a memory for the previous query
    int N = 50; //can be any number
    foreach (var q in query) { //query is IOrderedEnumerable or IEnumerable
        if (topNFoos.Count == 0 || !topNFoos.Any(foo => areBarsSimilar(foo.Bars, q.Bars)))
            topNFoos.Add(q);
        if (topNFoos.Count >= N) //We have had enough Foo
            break;
    }
}
```

The `topNFoos` `List` will serve as a memory of the previous query and we can skip the `Foo q` in the `foreach` loop which already have identical `Bars` with `Any` of the `Foo` in the `topNFoos`.

My question is, is there any way to do that in `LINQ` (*fully* `LINQ`)?

```
var topNFoos = from q in query
               //put something
               select q;
```

If the "memory" required is from a particular query item `q` or a variable outside of the query, then we could use `let` variable to cache it:

```
int index = 0;
var topNFoos = from q in query
               let qc = index++ + q.Id //depends on q or variable outside like index, then it is OK
               select q;
```

But if it must come from the *previous querying of the query itself* then things start to get more troublesome.

Is there any way to do that?

---

**Edit:**

*(I currently am [creating a test case](https://github.com/ian5666987/linqmemorytest/blob/master/Program.cs) (github link) for the answers. Still figuring out how can I test all the answers fairly)*

*(Most of the answers below are aimed to solve my particular question and are in themselves good (Rob's, spender's, and David B's answers which use `IEqualityComparer` are particularly awesome). Nevertheless, if there is anyone who can give answer to my more general question "does LINQ have a way to "memorize" its previous query results while querying", I would also be glad)*

*(Apart from the significant difference in performance for the particular case I presented above when using fully/partial LINQ, one answer aiming to answer my general question about LINQ memory is Ivan Stoev's. Another one with good combination is Rob's. As to make myself clearer, I look for general and efficient solution, if there is any, using LINQ)*

Comment: Your "Without LINQ" case seems to mainly use LINQ.

Comment: Is this fact `Now, if two or more Foo have same collection of Bar (no matter what the order is), they are considered as similar Foo.` considered true for your whole application, or only in this instance?

Comment: @spender you are right, what I actually mean is *partial* LINQ, I should update that...

Comment: So what are you actually trying to do? Group a sequence of `Foo` by the contents of their `Bars` collection?

Comment: @Rob it is for the particular instance of this query the `areBarsSimilar` is to be used...

Comment: So, from your code, it looks to me like you're trying to build a collection of `N` non-similar Foos. Is this right?

Comment: @spender yes. :) for this case in particular. The general case would be to have a memory of the previous querying results while querying though...

Comment: If the `Bar` collections will not/should not/don't need to contain duplicates, you might consider replacing them with a set based collection such as `HashSet<Foo>` that won't store duplicates. This, in turn, will make for much speedier comparisons of the two collections.

Comment: @Ian Doing this in pure linq is described at the end of Rob's answer. Doing it without an appropriate IEqualityComparer seems pointlessly long winded. By having one in place, it allows `GroupBy`'s own "memory"  to be used when assembling groups. Mainaining statefulness between different linq statements is a fool's errand and an abuse. Linq shouldn't rely on side-effects. The IEqualityComparer way *is* the way, and you can use it in Linq, as demonstrated by Rob. WinWin

Comment: @spender I do not disagree with you. I made the test and saw the performance result and it made me realize that some LINQ solutions for this particular case could be a lot worse than having `IEqualityComparer` (your answer and Rob's in particular). Still, my question of whether or not it is possible to have LINQ *and* efficient solution with some memory in general remains. It does not mean that *abusing* LINQ is good - I do *not* ask for that. I merely asking *if* there is a better way of doing that in LINQ *without* abusing it. This is an "exploration" to me - in that sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it's ... possible. But this is *far* from performant code.

```
var res = query.Select(q => new {
    original = q, 
    matches = query.Where(innerQ => areBarsSimilar(q.Bars, innerQ.Bars))
}).Select(g => new { original = g, joinKey = string.Join(",", g.matches.Select(m => m.Id)) })
.GroupBy (g => g.joinKey)
.Select(g => g.First().original.original)
.Take(N);
```

This assumes that the `Id`s are unique for each Foo (you could also use their `GetHashCode()`, I suppose).

A much better solution is to either keep what you've done, or implement a custom comparer, as follows:

---

***Note:*** As pointed out in the comments by @spender, the below `Equals` and `GetHashCode` will not work for collections with duplicates. Refer to their answer for a better implementation - however, the usage code would remain the same

---

```
class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo left, Foo right)
    {
        return left.Bars.Count() == right.Bars.Count() && //have the same amount of bars
            left.Bars.Select(x => x.Id)
            .Except(right.Bars.Select(y => y.Id))
            .ToList().Count == 0; //and when excepted returns 0, mean similar bar
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo foo)
    {
        unchecked {
            int hc = 0;
            if (foo.Bars != null)
                foreach (var p in foo.Bars)
                hc ^= p.GetHashCode();
            return hc;
        }
    }
}
```

And then your query becomes simply:

```
var res = query
    .GroupBy (q => q, new MyComparer())
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .Take(N);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please give me some time to look through this and the other answer, you have got my upvote for the significant effort though...

Comment: Hah! I took the same approach and was just looking up the `GroupBy` syntax. Beware the case where there are unmatched numbers of duplicates in the `Bars` collection, because your `GetHashCode` implementation is not consistent with the set based operations of the `Equals` implementation. I chose to do a `SequenceEqual` instead to ensure that the hashcode and equals implementations are in complete agreement.

Comment: @spender Yep - you're right, I was a bit lazy and just used the original `Equals` implementation (mainly an example of the `IEqualityComparer`). I'd definitely go with your answer though, much cleaner implementation of the `Equals` and it's consistent

Comment: @Rob your answer answers most of my concern, giving examples, and having pretty good performance. :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not going to answer your question directly, but rather, propose a method that will be fairly optimally efficient for filtering the first N non-similar items.

First, consider writing an `IEqualityComparer<Foo>` that uses the `Bars` collection to measure equality. Here, I'm assuming that the lists might contain duplicate entries, so have quite a strict definition of similarity:

```
public class FooSimilarityComparer:IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo a, Foo b)
    {
        //called infrequently
        return a.Bars.OrderBy(bar => bar.Id).SequenceEqual(b.Bars.OrderBy(bar => bar.Id));
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Foo foo)
    {
        //called frequently
        unchecked
        {
            return foo.Bars.Sum(b => b.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

You can really efficiently get the top `N` non-similar items by using a `HashSet` with the IEqualityComparer above:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> someFoos; //= some list of Foo
var hs = new HashSet<Foo>(new FooSimilarityComparer());
foreach(var f in someFoos)
{
    hs.Add(f); //hashsets don't add duplicates, as measured by the FooSimilarityComparer
    if(hs.Count >= 50)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

@Rob s approach above is broadly similar, and shows how you can use the comparer directly in LINQ, but pay attention to the comments I made to his answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please give me some time to look through this and the other answer, you have got my upvote for the significant effort though...

Comment: Is the sum of hashes a good hash? Would a folded/aggregated bitwise-XOR produce better results?

Comment: @Mephy aggregating xor in the case of duplicates would be disastrous to a reliable hash

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerable<Foo> dissimilarFoos =
  from foo in query
  let key = string.Join('|',
    from bar in foo.Bars
    order by bar.Id
    select bar.Id.ToString())
  group foo by key into g
  select g.First();

IEnumerable<Foo> firstDissimilarFoos =
  dissimilarFoos.Take(50);
```

---

Sometimes, you may not like the behavior of groupby in the above queries.  At the time the query is enumerated, groupby will enumerate the entire source.  If you only want partial enumeration, then you should switch to Distinct and a Comparer:

```
class FooComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
  private string keyGen(Foo foo)
  {
    return string.Join('|',
      from bar in foo.Bars
      order by bar.Id
      select bar.Id.ToString());
  }
  public bool Equals(Foo left, Foo right)
  {
    if (left == null || right == null) return false;
    return keyGen(left) == keyGen(right);
  }
  public bool GetHashCode(Foo foo)
  {
    return keyGen(foo).GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

then write:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> dissimilarFoos = query.Distinct(new FooComparer());
IEnumerable<Foo> firstDissimilarFoos = dissimilarFoos.Take(50);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I currently am writing a test case to evaluate all the answers. Please give me some time to look through this and the other answers, you have got my upvote for the significant effort though...

Answer (score 1):

Idea. You might be able to hack something by devising your own fluent interface of mutators over a cache that you'd capture in "let x = ..." clauses, along the lines of,

```
from q in query
let qc = ... // your cache mechanism here
select ...
```

but I suspect you'll have to be careful to limit the updates to your cache to those "let ..." only, as I doubt the implementation of the standard Linq operators and extensions methods will be happy if you allow such side effects to happen in their back through predicates applied in the "where", or "join", "group by", etc, clauses.

'HTH,

Comment: ah yes, I wonder what could be in the `qc=...` actually. :) if it is a variable resulting from a particular query item `q` or a variable outside the query, then it should be OK. But if it must come *from the previous querying of the query itself* then things start to get more troublesome. And that is the point of the question actually. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess by "full LINQ" you mean standard LINQ operators/`Enumerable` extension methods.

I don't think this can be done with LINQ query syntax. From standard methods the only one that supports mutable processing state is [Enumerable.Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate(v=vs.110).aspx), but it gives you nothing more than a LINQ flavor over the plain `foreach`:

```
var result = query.Aggregate(new List<Foo>(), (list, next) =>
{
    if (list.Count < 50 && !list.Any(item => areBarsSimilar(item.Bars, next.Bars)))
        list.Add(next);
    return list;
});
```

Since looks like we are allowed to use helper methods (like `areBarsSimilar`), the best we can do is to make it at least look more LINQ-ish by defining and using a custom extension method

```
var result = query.Aggregate(new List<Foo>(), (list, next) => list.Count < 50 && 
    !list.Any(item => areBarsSimilar(item.Bars, next.Bars)) ? list.Concat(next) : list);
```

where the custom method is

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static List<T> Concat<T>(this List<T> list, T item) { list.Add(item); return list; }
}
```

But note that compared to vanilla `foreach`, `Aggregate` has an additional drawback of not being able to exit earlier, thus will consume the whole input sequence (which besides the performance also means it doesn't work with infinite sequences).

**Conclusion:** While this should answer your original question, i.e. it's technically possible to do what you are asking for, LINQ (like the standard SQL) is not well suited for such type of processing.

Comment: This gives me one more answer to evaluate! please give me some time to look through this and the other answers, you have got my `upvote` for the significant effort though. :) (and, it is *you* again!)

Comment: @Ian Yeah, it's me again:) But seriously, I think the subject of the question has changed significantly. Most of the answers are trying to solve the concrete issue in a most effective way, and I saw you are preparing a performance tests. That's not fair because it's comparing apples to oranges. There are pretty good solutions, but for a different question, most probably under `algorithms` and `performance` tags.

Comment: Good to see you - alive *and* active. :) You are right in saying that my original question was to find the solution in general, rather than solution in particular. I merely put the particular solution because it can give picture to the general question. Nevertheless, it is also true that the reason why I am trying to find general solution is because I think it could be more *efficient*, which is also part of my original concern. That's why I think your solution still answer essential part of my question. But of the other part, a test might be required. This is why I create a test.

Comment: I also think it's a good general problem, but I doubt that pure LINQ solution can beat a good specifically engineered data structure/algorithm (like the `HashSet` solution by @spender). Anyway, good to see you too! And slow down a bit man, we can't catch you up :) Just kidding, cheers and happy coding!

Comment: Btw, speaking about performance, your `areBarsSimilar` function can be speeded up a bit by eliminating the `ToList` call - `return bars1.Count == bars2.Count && !bars1.Select(x => x.Id).Except(bars2.Select(y => y.Id)).Any();`

Comment: ah yes, you are right! `Any()` seems like you are truly a master of `Any()` ;)